# Obtaining margin value and applying it to another element

Tags: jquery, css, margin

I have a container with margin auto for left and right. What I want to do is somehow get the value of this and apply it to another element. So no matter what size browser, the auto margins change and also update my desired element.

Not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want? It will alert the margin value. Store it in some variable and use it as you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/uv7hF/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($(".aa").css("margin"));
});

<div class="aa">
    a
</div>

.aa{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```